# How to set time zone in crystal reports java viewer (or pass a connection to)

Tags: java, oracle, session, crystal-reports, connection

is it somehow possible to set (or change) the time zone of the Oracle DB connection/session when using Crystal reports viewer for Java ?

I tried this method:

```
ReportClientDocument.setTimeZone(TimeZone tz);
```

but it didn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I found a workaround for local applications, because I use the JDBC driver the default time zone is taken into consideration.
We can set it with following code:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone tz);
```

This way we can ensure that the proper time zone is used.

Nevertheless there is a one big BUT:
We cannot use it with web services because we could have clients with different time zones.
Not to speak of other services relying on that value.

So the question we actually should ask is:

*Can we pass a connection instance to the ReportViewerBean?*